Volvo V40 EGR error, despite clean and valve replace!
I have a 2015 Volvo V40 D2, who's EGR system was clogged up with soot around 6 months ago (I bought it second hand at around 27000 miles a year ago). Warranty covered replacement of EGR valve and cleaning of the EGR cooler. Everything was fine for 6 months.
Recently (6 months after above), my mechanic cleaned the fuel injectors for preventative maintenance, and performed a software update. (The software update advised a replacement of EGR valve and cooler, and also left an ECM/PCM checksum error.)
A few days later, an intermittent EGR error returned, usually accompanied by a shuddering when changing into 3rd gear (only occasionally). Error was cleared but returned after 60 miles.
My mechanic is a bit at a loss, does anyone have any advice? I've attached the precise error, and a freeze frame (I can't interpret much of it). Any help much appreciated in this complicated issue!
Best wishes




Edit: Paulster2 noted some funky values in the freeze frame, so I found a way to record some time traces as I revved the car to various degrees (see RPM in plots), and also left it idle. Seems like the EGR can reach 100% error when the EGR duty is commanding 0%. Is this bad? I don't really know how to interpret the rest of the traces. (Edit 2: the headline number on each plot can be a bit confusing, rather check out the Y-axis scale on each plot.)
Idle:


Revving:





Something seems screwy with a few of the values in the top left box.  Absolute Load Value is showing 92%. If so, your engine would be revving to high heaven if in neutral sitting still. Commanded EGR Value is at 85%, which is about 60% higher than it should be (could be because it isn't flowing enough?). And fuel rail pressure reading is bonkers ... even if this is the high pressure side on a direct injected engine, it is 3x higher than it should be, even at full load (~15168 kPa would be max at full load). Those readings are REALLY strange.

Hi @Paulster2, many thanks for your help interpreting! I have no idea what the values should be. Based on your comments, I tried to record some traces as I revved the car. If you have a few minutes to take a look,  please let me know if the numbers make sense, or it they're also odd.

As an Engineer, I out a lot of trust in garages over the years, however have become wiserin that time. My Volvo V40 D2 had problems you describe. The shudder, which more like the car hiccuping intermittently. The fuel consumption had gone up. Volvo assured me they had fixed the problem as car was under warranty. They basically reset the engine warning light with an OBD2 unit, and charged me, for fixing problem. I asked them for the parts they had exchanged, non-provided, so had my doubts..moreso problem still their, engine warning light back on. Took car to local garage, asked them to check out.They mentioned it was probally the EGR valve. Took car back to Volvo, who again had car, and returned same. £600.00 later told EGR valve replaced. I asked if the cooler was cleaned as like mentioned gets sooted up-that had been done. So off I go, and within 2 days the hiccuping, and the engine warning light back on. So I booked a week off work, looked at video on You tube, took the cooler off, EGR valve off. Nevr been renewed all covered in carbon. When I looked closer at the EGR VALVE WHICH HAD CARBON AROUND THE VALVE. I noted the valve had become jammed and as a consequence the valve stem, or shaft is sheared across, so I took photos of this along with milage of car, used my Wife's car to show garages that I have been charged for work which has never fixed issue, and issue is still present in a broken valve shaft in the EGR valve, which if carbon had been removed would have been noted. Also they never fitted a new EGR valve originally. So thats me finished with that Volvo garage.
The local garage, have admitted they did not change the EGR valve, but aid that the broken valve shaft which is seized in the EGR would cause problem.
So now I am looking just for a valve spindle for the EGR valve, but looks like have to buy the whole lot. The local garage have said if I get one they would fit it for free as goodwill measure.
Currently around £350 i can get one for online, however I am not saying this is your problem but-I have zero faith in any garages-as only as good as the knowledge and experience of the mechanics working in them.
As an engineer, when we strip machinery down, we take photos, to show the issues, back to customer, so they can see the state of the items, and once stripped we then bae our quotes on replacements, and all parts replaced given back to customer. If only garages would do this!
I would have your EGR revisited, as looks like problem is still with this.
